# python-wnck set focus to window

Tags: python, wnck

I'm trying to set focus to a window using python-wnck. 
The only docs I could find related to this library are from https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/WnckWindow.html

Using some code I found on another question here at SO, I was able to search for windows using the window title, but I'm not sure how to get a window to focus. 
From the above docs I found the function:

```
wnck_window_activate(WnckWindow *window, guint32 timestamp);
```

So in python I tried using this function like "window.activate(0)", but this appears to fail, the icon on my taskbar flashed but it doesn't get focus.
In the terminal I get the message:

```
 (windowTest.py:17485): Wnck-WARNING: Received a timestamp of 0; window activation may not function properly
```

So I think I may actually need to put in a valid timestamp but not sure how to get this.

This is the code Im using sofar:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import wnck
import re
import sys

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

titlePattern = re.compile('.*Geany.*')

windows = screen.get_windows()
for w in windows:
  if titlePattern.match(w.get_name()):
    print w.get_name()
    w.activate(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple
I just needed to "import time" then pass "int(time.time())" into the activate function

Working code:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import wnck
import re
import sys
import time

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

titlePattern = re.compile('.*Geany.*')

windows = screen.get_windows()
for w in windows:
  if titlePattern.match(w.get_name()):
    print w.get_name()
    w.activate(int(time.time()))
```

Comment: 'w.activate(int(time.time()))' is not what you want. I think the 'timestamp' is supposed to be a returned by the 'activate(timestamp)' call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I'm still confused. I see this is a bug that had been reported etc., but my case seems to be kind of the opposite. putting in a timestamp causes my app to not bring focus to the window and causes Alt-tab to do nothing. But putting in (0) makes it work except that there still is the warning (in the terminal window).

Answer (score 0):

To get away from the `Wnck-WARNING`, you need to send a valid timestamp with the `w.activate()`  function.  The way that I found to do this is to use:

> now = gtk.gdk.x11_get_server_time(gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window())
>
> w.activate(now)

There really should be an easier way to do this, or `wnck` should allow a timestamp of `0` to mean `now` like most of the gtk libraries use.